# Why is it suggested to attach the onClickListener to the ViewHolder?

Tags: android, performance, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

I don't see why it is effective to apply the listener to the holder.

I spent much of the day looking at articles. The topics here on stackoverflow covered the range well. 
The choices I found:

- Attach to TextView - creates multiple listeners.
- Attach to ViewHolder - again creates multiple listeners, unless you create a listener and then use that to attach which you can also do with the TextView.
- Attach a onItemTouchListener - a surprisingly complicated way.

What I did not see was just a straight forward implements `View.OnClickListener` attached to the adapter.  If you do this, then generate the one `public void onClick(View view)`, and give the adapter a copy of the `RecyclerView` and then assign the Adapter (this) as the listener to the item view you have inflated in `onCreateViewHolder`. Then access the position through the `RecyclerView` `getChildAdapterPosition` function. See code snippets.

```
//create adapter class implementing the on click listener
public class WordListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<WordListAdapter.WordViewHolder> implements View.OnClickListener {
    private final LinkedList<String> mWordList;
    private LayoutInflater mInFlater;
    private final RecyclerView recyclerView;

    //in constructor, pass in RecyclerView created in MainActivity 
    public WordListAdapter(Context context, LinkedList<String> wordList, RecyclerView rView) {
        recyclerView = rView; <----
        mInFlater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.mWordList = wordList;
    }

    //implementation of View.OnClickListener makes
    @Override 
    public void onClick(View view) {
        //get the position of the item that was clicked
        int mPosition = recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(view); <----

        //other code to do what you want with the list(eg. String element = mWordList.get(mPosition);)
    }

    //And you set your pointer in the adapter class
    @Override
    public WordListAdapter.WordViewHolder onCreateViewHolder( @NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View mItemView = mInFlater.inflate(R.layout.wordlist_item, parent, false);
        mItemView.setOnClickListener(this); <----
        return new WordViewHolder(mItemView, this);
    }
```

It seams to me that this answer is simple, and has the advantage of a single thread on click listener that is all handled in the list adapter.

I guess, I mostly wanted to share my solution on a closed topic but I certainly welcome any suggestions as to why this might not be better.  This is actually, my solution to challenge2 in Android fundamentals 04.5 RecyclerView.

Comment: Sorry, text is clumsy. I didn't know it would simplify the formatting on the text that much.  I see now that there are more formatting functions in the editor.

Comment: `Why is it suggested` you should ask the man that suggested it, not us.

Comment: Good point Vlad! Hopefully, though it is now useful to someone researching the topic?

Comment: Thanks to whomever tidied up the text! Brought my bullet list to life.

Comment: Ok, I think I get it. Thanks W0rmH0le, for the edit.

Answer (score 0):

The primary reason is is suggested to attach the onClickListener to the view holder as opposed to the adapter itself is because the view is what is being clicked on when a user clicks on an item within the Recyclerview.

The `Holder` you refer to is a class that contains the view and applying the click listener to this holder allows you to differentiate which view (position / item) is actually being clicked.

It's similar to explaining why you would attach a click listener to the button in a layout versus the entire layout itself. Sure, you could attach the click listener to the entire layout, but a user might intend to click on something else in your view as opposed to the button and you would have no way of distinguishing which one was clicked since your clickListener does not help to identify which.

Comment: Silmarilos, you have a good point that the holder returns its' position through getLayoutPosition.  I accessed this in my listener through the RecylerView.GetChildAdapterPosition().  It just seems to me that attaching a new listener to each holder creates more overhead, Possibly the system manages them better than I think?

Comment: I feel like position really is the only relevant info returned from the holder since all of the "behind the scenes" processing is usually on the list itself and possibly the underlying database.